# how to make a macro work in flat assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, fasm

I wanted to test a small assembler program using the flat assembler (FASM), however I ran into problems when a macro was used:

---

```
scount    =     0
smult     =     320
label screenoff word
rept 200
dw        smult*scount
scount    = scount + 1
endm
```

---

Can anyone help me with getting this to work, using flat assembler?
It is supposed to create an array of 200 words (words defined in label, 200 times with the `rept` directive).

I get `Error: unexpected characters when trying to compile in flat assembler vers. 1.71.22 (editor vers 3.11 beta 3, interface version 0.97.01)`.
Error is highlighted in line `dw smult*scount`.

A pointer to help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works in Turbo Assembler (TASM vers. 1.4) together with DOSBox 0.74, however I would like to build without the use of DOSBox, that is why I tried using flat assembler -- perhaps TASM can be used together with C::B -- any suggestions?

Comment: Consult the [FASM manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual). The macro is supposed to be enclosed by `{}`, and so is the part that you want to `rept`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the first line to actually start a macro definition.
Look it up in the manual!

```
...  <-- Missing here
scount    =     0
smult     =     320
label screenoff word
rept 200
dw        smult*scount
scount    = scount + 1
endm
```

EDIT

Variant 1 - Use it with `SetupArray200`

```
macro SetupArray200 { times 200 dw (%-1)*320 }
```

Variant 2 - Use it with `SetupArray200`

```
macro SetupArray200
 {
  repeat 200
   dw (%-1)*320
  end repeat
 }
```

Variant 3 with parameters - use it with `SetupArray 200,320`

```
macro SetupArray scount,smult
 {
  repeat scount
   dw (%-1)*smult
  end repeat
 }
```

Comment: it is a label macro and it actually works when using TASM, but what do you suggest to write as start ?

Comment: @serup I've added some examples to my answer.